# how to create a windows7 image from an SD card

Tags: installation, windows, virtualbox, ubuntu-netbook, sd-card

Question:
I have an SD card, with windows 7 files in it (as in any bootable DVD) and I want to use it, to install Windows7 in an Ubuntu virtualBox. How to make that happen?

Comment: Installing Windows in a VirtualBox in Ubuntu is no different than doing so in Windows or, for that matter, than installing Windows on a real computer. Basically, you need to boot from that medium, which will start the setup program (in your case - to boot your VirtualBox, not the real machine). My point is that the question is not really related to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can use genisoimage. I do use this terminal app for creating ISO images out of files.

1. Installation: sudo apt-get install genisoimage
2. Usage: genisoimage -o /home/nomadic/image.iso /media/sdcard